# Set default options in cups

Tags: cups

The CUPS docs say to change the printer defaults by ....

```
lpoptions -p printer/instance -o name=value
```

The option I want to change is

```
FXColorMode/Output Color: *Color Black
```

So I have tried ..

```
lpoptions -p test_printer/FXColorMode/Output -o Color=Black
```

But I get the error

```
Unable to add printer or instance: Undefined error: 0
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You want to try

```
lpoptions -p test_printer -o FXColorMode/Output/Color=Black
```